# $GL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ and the crystallographic restriction theorem

Tags: group-theory, symmetry

In the comments on [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/122254/what-are-the-possible-orders-of-elements-in-gl2-mathbbr), Robert Israel proved that the order of an element in $GL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ can be $2,3$ or $6$ (or infinite). This result is remarkedly reminiscent of the [crystallographic restriction theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystallographic_restriction_theorem), but I can't seem to find the relation. Is this mere coincidence, or is there something deep buried here?

Comment: This fact is used in the only prof I've ever seen of the CRT, so yes, there is a connection.

Comment: In the wiki article there are four proofs, but I don't see this fact appearing in none of them. What is the proof you are referring to?

Comment: It's from *Modern Algebra: An Introduction* by John Durbin if I remember correctly. I'm afraid I don't have the book on hand.

Comment: Don't forget $1$ and $4$.

Comment: They, of course, follow triviałly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The connection is that any lattice in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^2$, so any (linear) group of symmetries of a lattice injects into $\text{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: Thanks. One has also to add two lines about why it is also valid for lattices in $\mathbb{R}^3$, but it's fairly easy.